# Can a click on image in a form open a combobox which is defined in the same form (ionic4)

Tags: angular, combobox, ionic4

On a html page I have a combobox and a image. I want that the combobox which can be clicked on the arrow button of the combobox, can also select an item from the combobox. The image is in a grid cell.

The combobox is created in this way:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Key for 'A-Button':</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="aButton">A-Button
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let aButton of ControllerButton" [value]="aButton">
      {{aButton}}
    </ion-select-option></ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to another component by giving it a `#name` like that.

[Template Reference Variable - Angular - Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var)

Here is an example from the docs which you should be able to expand for your scenario:

```
<input #phone placeholder="phone number" />

<!-- lots of other elements -->

<!-- phone refers to the input element; pass its `value` to an event handler -->
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template reference like rtpHarry suggests. To make the answer suit for your needs, when you have marked the template reference, you have access to ionic `Select` method(s), you want to manually call [`open`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#methods). So mark the template reference:

```html
<ion-select formControlName="aButton" #ionSelect>
```

Now in your click event on the image you can call `open` like:

```html
(click)="ionSelect.open()"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I want to do it on another form too in the same way but this time the control is a Menu-Item. This component has a present function "async present(child)". What does "child" mean?

Comment: Could you link what doc you are talking about?

Comment: Extended the question.

Comment: Usually we should ask just one question, and especially not add another question to already answered question ;) But `child` simply means the popover-component you have created. In this case `IonicContextMenuContentComponent`

Comment: Oh no, sorry... as to the documentation at ionic, it seems that `$event` is passed from the template

Comment: but anyway, just set a click event to call to open the popover... whatever you have named your function. for example `presentPopover` like in the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover